# Angular: Service looking after a component

Tags: angular

We have an Angular application where we need to show some success/warning/error messages. Current solution is that we have a component (which is placed inside every component, where we need to show some message, so almost everywhere), which shows the message and it's display is influenced by component variable, so we need to set and unset this variable all the time.

I thought there could be a clean solution of some service which would 'look after' the 'message component' in a sense it would

- Show the message box (and delete an old one if there is any)
- Hide the message box on command
- Maybe keep a reference of the message box?

This message box has absolute position, so it can be placed anywhere in HTML code.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sound like you want a toast service.
I recently used https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-toastr and im quit happy with this.